How can I select elements with a specific class while excluding those with any additional classes
Suppose, I have three links,
<a class="a b">1</a>
<a class="a">1</a>
<a class="a">1</a>

Now i just want links which only have the class "a". If i use document.querySelectorAll('.a') then i will get all three of the links.
I know i can use document.querySelectorAll('.a:not(.b)'). but for that i need to know all the class name specifically. I just want to get the link which only had the class "a".

[...document.querySelectorAll('a.a')].filter(l => l.classList.length === 1);

I would filter the original results by checking the length of the classList.


const withA = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")];
const onlyA = withA.filter(a => a.classList.length == 1);
console.log(onlyA.length);
<a class="a b">1</a>
<a class="a">1</a>
<a class="a">1</a>




It might be a bit of a hack, but if the goal is to find the exact class value of "a" then you can use an attribute selector:


document.querySelectorAll('a[class="a"]').forEach(x => x.innerHTML = "2");
<a class="a b">1</a>
<a class="a">1</a>
<a class="a">1</a>




thanks for the response, but can you explain it, especially the innerHTML part.

@user27719048: "The innerHTML part" was just arbitrary functionality to demonstrate what's being selected.  The attribute selector being used in querySelectorAll is selecting elements based on an attribute value.

That's slick @David, but don't forget the . (period) in front of the first a.

@RayWallace: In this one example that change would result in the same output, but be aware that the period changes the selector.  I'm currently selecting <a> elements where the class attribute is exactly "a".  You're proposing we instead select any elements with a class value of a where the class attribute is exactly "a".  For the markup shown the result would be the same, so it makes no difference here.  But for future readers it's important to understand the difference.

Of course you are correct @David. I was concentrating on the class names and forgot what elements were being used. Sorry about that.
